# Dependence of the type of a property on the value of an array-typed sibling property

Tags: typescript

P.S. I am aware of many questions regarding type dependence of sibling properties, but most of them are either where the sibling property is an enum (where you can just do a simple discrim union) or the answers say "tsc can't do it".

Say one has a type `X`, that has a single `name` property, and another type `Y`, that has two properties, `xList` and `z`, where `z` is dependent on `xList`, like so:

```js
type X = { name: string }

type Y<TXList extends X[] = X[]> = {
  xList: TXList
  z: TXList[number]['name']
}
```

After defining the specific value for `xList`, the goal here is for typescript to infer (and so the intellisense to show) the available values for `z`, i.e.:

```js
const y: Y = {
  xList: [{ name: 'foo' }, { name: 'bar' }],
  z: '' // <-- Typescript infers as "foo" | "bar"
}
```

This does not work with the above types, even though we have clearly stated the dependence of `z` on `xList`!

**EDIT 1**

Assume that one already has an ident helper function for `Y`, i.e.

```js
const createY= <TY extends Y>(y: T): T => y
```

Comment: tsc can't do it

Comment: That is, without a "helper" function to infer the generics for you. It's probably as simple as `const createY = <TXList extends X[]>(y: Y<TXList>) => y;` and then using it `const y = createY([...]);`. Ugly and it seems like its unnecessary, but unfortunately in the current state of TypeScript what you are asking for is not possible.

Comment: I already have one of these ident helpers for `Y`, i.e. `const createY= <TY extends Y>(y: T): T =>y`. I need to fully infer `y` with this, so how would I include inference of the `xList` too?